# Memory leak using raphael.js with hover

Tags: javascript

There is a serious memory leak happening using the Raphael library pie chart WITH the hover attribute.  If I remove the code that includes the hover attribute it works great and when I add it back in the memory footprint steadily grows and hovering over the piechart increases the memory footprint even more so.  Unlike most other examples I'm using window.setInterval to constantly update the page (if this helps any).
I'm at a loss as to how to correct this issue and reaching out for some help.

Below is the basics of what I'm doing...using pretty much the dynamic pieChart on the Raphael website and adding an interval timer to it.  I cant however figure out how to utilize the hover effect without the memory issue???:

```
 window.onload = setInterval(drawThePie, 10000);
function drawThePie() {
    var mainCont = parent.frames["main"].document;
    mainCont.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = "Getting data..";

    //..Setting values for pieChart and legend into arrays here

    //..Looping through color array and setting values for colorlist below

            var r = Raphael("holder");
    var aCircle = r.aCircle(85,85,78).attr({fill: "black"});

            pie = r.piechart(85,85,75,data, {"legend": legend, "legendpos": "east", colors: colorlist });
    if(dataNotZero > 0) { mainCont.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = "";}

            pie.hover(function () {
                this.sector.stop();
                this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

                if (this.label) {
                    this.label[0].stop();
                    this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                }
            }, function () {
                this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

                if (this.label) {
                    this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "bounce");
                    this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It can not see your all code. so i just can guess...

maybe this part was worng

```
this.sector.scale
```

this part of code maybe got some value which hava some  DOM Reference. when the function was got end,the value still not release the DOM Reference.